# Elasticsearch all terms in document field should match to the query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a field in the Elastic Index containing multiple words. ie

```
field : "nice house"
```

I only want to find Documents, if the user has all words of this field in his query string, the query string may contain additional words that are not in the field so i.e.

```
nice (should not match)
nice room (should not match)
nice house (should match)
nice house bro (should match)
```

minimum_should match or AND don't help here any tips how to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to achieve your use case. But you can use a [percolate query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) to achieve your use case

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "query": {
        "type": "percolator"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": {
        "query": "nice house",
        "operator": "AND"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Query:**

> nice (should not match)

```
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "name": "nice"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be:

```
"hits": []
```

---

> nice house bro (should match)

```
{
  "query": {
    "percolate": {
      "field": "query",
      "document": {
        "name": "nice house bro"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
 "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67433387",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.26152915,
        "_source": {
          "query": {
            "match": {
              "name": {
                "query": "nice house",
                "operator": "AND"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "fields": {
          "_percolator_document_slot": [
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @revelator did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)